# Hardhat deploy smart contract by micro service server NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ethereum, hardhat

I have a NodeJs server, I wish to deploy a smart contract by Hardhat when a request arrives on the server.

The idea is the following:

```
User -> Server A -> Server B -> deploy smart contract
```

The user uses an application like a web site or others (without Wallet like Metamask), sends a Json to Server A that sends a request to Server B. Server B will deploy a smart contract on Ethereum.

I'm able to deploy on Ethereum using `npx hardhat deploy` but I have not found an example or guide for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

same here, I asked on several forums but no answer so far...